# @RequestBody optional (e.g. required=false)

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

Is there a way to make the @RequestBody annotation options (e.g. required=false) like RequestParam supports?

My main path through the code is with a POST.  However, I'd like to also support a basic GET request via a browser basic http request for debugging purposes.  However when I try to do that I get a 415 unsupported media error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My main path through the code is with a POST. However, I'd like to also support a basic GET request via a browser

To do this, use the `method` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myPath", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String doSomething() {
   ...
}

@RequestMapping(value="/myPath", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSomething(@RequestBody payload) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: fastest way to fix it. couldn't be bothered to find what configuration I need to add to Spring to change the default behaviour. I'm using Spring3.2 and was getting error 415 if I send a GET request, this is the fastes solution.

Answer (score 7):

@RequestBody can apparently now be set as optional as of Spring 3.2M1: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9239

However I have tested this in Spring 3.2M2 and its throwing an exception when sending through a null body even after setting required=false, instead of passing through a null. This issue has been confirmed and has been fixed, schedule for 3.2 RC1

Answer (score 3):

Is there a way to make the @RequestBody annotation options (e.g. required=false) like RequestParam supports?

In short, I don't believe so,
 but you can do it manually from the input stream:

```
@Autowired
private MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter;

RestResponse<String> updateViewingCard(@PathVariable(value = "custome") String customer,
        @RequestParam(value = "p1", required = false) String p1,
        @RequestParam(value = "p2", required = false) String p2, 
        // @RequestBody MyPayloadType payload,     Can't make this optional
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)  throws... {

    MyPayloadType payload = null;
    if (0 < request.getContentLength()) {
            payload = this.mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),
                    MyPayloadType.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. In Spring 4 or Spring Boot 1.5, you can do it in the following way:

```java
@PostMapping("/error-report")
public String errorReport(@RequestBody(required = false) ErrorReportModel errorReportModel) {

    // YOUR LOGIC

    return "page-to-return";
}
```